# manipulate the colours in a Bitmap android

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, bitmap

I have a QrCode which i want to change its colours to white and blue...
I can do it using the following code:

```
val bitmap = qrgEncoder.encodeAsBitmap()
        val width = bitmap.width
        val height = bitmap.height
        // All are 0, or black, by default
        for (y in 0 until height) {
            for (x in 0 until width) {
                bitmap.getPixel(x, y).also {
                    if(it != -1)
                        bitmap.setPixel(x, y, ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.defaultTextColor, null))
                    else
                        bitmap.setPixel(x, y, ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.toolbarColor, null))
                }
            }
        }
        // Setting Bitmap to ImageView
        qrImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

but this is too slow... so I am wondering what is the best approach to do the same thing and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different solutions, I realised the only way is to manipulate the pixels. 
The following code is the optimum solution for now:

```
val pixelsArray = IntArray(mWidth * mHeight)
val newColor1 = getColor(context!!, R.color.color1)
val newColor2 = getColor(context!!, R.color.color2)
bitmap.getPixels(pixelsArray, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight)
for (y in 0 until pixelsArray.size) {
    if (pixelsArray[y] != -1)
        pixelsArray[y] = newColor1
    else
    pixelsArray[y] = newColor2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

note for accepted answer by msc87,

to save pixelsArray back to bitmap use:

```
bitmap.setPixels(pixelsArray,0,mWidth,0,0,mWidth,maskHeight)
```

you can also replace getColour to: (if needed)

```
Color.argb(255,0,177,64)
```

ect..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31230503)

Answer (score -2):

You can set a Drawable tint:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#setTint(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int)

```
val bitmap: Bitmap = ...

val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)

DrawableCompat.setTint(bitmapDrawable, Color.BLUE)
```

Comment: would you care to explain or give me a sample code please?